# Save Picture to Camera Roll with Title

Tags: ios, photosframework

I need to edit the title attribute in the metadata so I can later export the images using the Photos app, and use the title as filename.

I've looked around but I can't find any up-to-date code snippet on how to save a picture to the camera roll with a title as metadata.

Can anybody tell me whether this is actually possible on iOS 8 and up?
If so, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: This link may help you 
http://ootips.org/yonat/how-to-set-the-image-name-when-saving-to-the-camera-roll/

Comment: @iOS_Binod Thanks, I came across that one, but it uses the ALAssetLibrary. According to the developer reference this has become deprecated in iOS 9.

Comment: Shot in the dark here. Manage to figure this out and happen to remember the answer?